Limiting the Scope of Variables in CMake to specific Projects/Subdirectories
I would like to set a variable that is available for modification in a third-party library which I have included as a subdirectory (add_subdirectory(.../third_party/libA)). The library allows me to enable/disable certain portions of the build process such as to including testing targets, for example: set(BUILD_TESTS OFF).
However, what am I to do if multiple libraries contain the same option, named the same? I understand there exists the PARENT_SCOPE option of set() for the "opposite direction" of what I am looking to accomplish, but is there a way to restrict the scope somehow such that I can do the following (simulated behavior below):
project(my_project)

set(libA_BUILD_TESTS OFF) # I DO NOT want to build tests for libA
add_subdirectory("${my_project_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/libA")

set(libB_BUILD_TESTS ON) # I DO want to build tests for libB
add_subdirectory("${my_project_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/libB")

Because I have no control over the variable names of the third-party library, variables libA_BUILD_TESTS and libB_BUILD_TESTS do not actually exist. They both simply have BUILD_TESTS.

Would it be possible to do this and expect each should be set properly? I am not familiar with
how CMake handles the timing of variable resolution...
set(BUILD_TESTS OFF)
add_subdirectory(.../third_party/libA)

set(BUILD_TESTS ON)
add_subdirectory(.../third_party/libB)


Is there a more explicit/safe way to declare that I want those two to be different
beyond sharing the same variable name? To me, reusing the same variable name seems
fundamentally prone to error and particularly "gross." I do not like this because it
makes the variable "stateful" which makes things harder to track during the build.

Am I even thinking about this fundamental variable-setting process correctly? Perhaps
my feelings in #2 are simply not "the way things are done."


Some random things I tried (unsuccessfully):
Settings properties specific to the subdirectory:
set(libA_dir "${my_project_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/libA")
set(libB_dir "${my_project_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/libB")

set_property(DIRECTORY ${libA_dir} PROPERTY BUILD_TESTS OFF)
set_property(DIRECTORY ${libB_dir} PROPERTY BUILD_TESTS ON)

Settings target properties (doesn't work as target doesn't yet exist):
# does not work because the libA target does not yet exist
set_target_properties(libA PROPERTIES BUILD_TESTS OFF) 

add_subdirectory("${my_project_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/libA")

# this does work based on how the third party CMake was written...
find_package(libA REQUIRED) 

Setting target properties after target is defined (doesn't work because the logic has
already been processed before seeing my set_target_properties):
add_subdirectory("${my_project_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/libA")

# does not work because the subdir was already included and seems to have not respected
# the options here due to timing/ordering.
set_target_properties(libA PROPERTIES BUILD_TESTS OFF)

# this does work based on how the third party CMake was written...
find_package(libA REQUIRED) 

Ultimately: I am looking to understand methods for ensuring "isolation" of variable assignment between these two libraries, especially when the same variable would have two different values (i.e. "I want to build tests for libA but not for libB"). Thank you.


Am I even thinking about this fundamental variable-setting process correctly?

I think the mental model you are using is missing a few pieces. I'd take a thorough read over the CMake documentation for variable scope, and specifically note how the words "scope" and "binding" are used. It would also help improve the question if you could share how libA and libB declare BUILD_TESTS so that we could know if its a cache variable or a normal variable.

Is there a more explicit/safe way to declare that I want those two to be different beyond sharing the same variable name?

I have two suggestions for you to try out depending on if you're able to edit the third_party directory
1. Separate libA and libB cmake configuration in different files at different directory scope.
If you make a wrapper directory with a CMakeLists.txt file for libA and libB, then any normal variables that you set in those wrapper directories will be encapsulated to just that directory. So for example if your project looks like this:
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── third_party
    ├── libA_wrapper
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   └── libA
    │       └── ...
    └── libB_wrapper
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        └── libB
            └── ...

top level CMakeLists.txt:
message("top_level 1st: BUILD_TESTS=${BUILD_TESTS}")
add_subdirectory(third_party/libA_wrapper)

message("top_level 2nd: BUILD_TESTS=${BUILD_TESTS}")

add_subdirectory(third_party/libB_wrapper)

message("top_level 3rd: BUILD_TESTS=${BUILD_TESTS}")

libA_wrapper/CmakeLists.txt:
set(BUILD_TESTS OFF)
message("third_part/libA_wrapper BUILD_TESTS=${BUILD_TESTS}")

add_subdirectory(libA)

libB_wrapper/CMakeLists.txt
set(BUILD_TESTS ON)
message("third_part/libB_wrapper BUILD_TESTS=${BUILD_TESTS}")

add_subdirectory(libB)

Then the BUILD_TESTS variable for each library will be independent from eachother, and your top level scope. The build output will look like this:
top_level 1st: BUILD_TESTS=
third_part/libA_wrapper BUILD_TESTS=OFF
top_level 2nd: BUILD_TESTS=
third_part/libB_wrapper BUILD_TESTS=ON
top_level 3rd: BUILD_TESTS=

2. Separate libA and libB configuration with block() scope
If it makes sense for your project to keep third party configuration in a single file, then you can use the block() keyword to create your own scope blocks. The following top level CMakeLists.txt is functionally equivalent to the above example:
top level CMakeLists.txt
message("top_level 1st: BUILD_TESTS=${BUILD_TESTS}")

block() # libA block scope is independent
set(BUILD_TESTS OFF)
message("libA BUILD_TESTS=${BUILD_TESTS}")
add_subdirectory(libA)
endblock()

message("top_level 2nd: BUILD_TESTS=${BUILD_TESTS}")

block() # libB block scope variables are independent
set(BUILD_TESTS ON)
message("libB BUILD_TESTS=${BUILD_TESTS}")
add_subdirectory(path/to/libB)
endblock()

message("top_level 3rd: BUILD_TESTS=${BUILD_TESTS}")

But beware of cache variables
The above examples will only work like I'm describing if BUILD_TESTS is declared as a normal variable( not a cache variable) in your project. Then you will need to change how you use set()


Is there a more explicit/safe way to declare that I want those two to be different beyond sharing the same variable name? To me, reusing the same variable name seems fundamentally prone to error and particularly "gross."

This question starts to get subjective so its harder to answer. I would feel that its prone to error (and gross) if you use the same variable name in the same scope to mean multiple things. However, I think its normal to use a variable with the same name in separate scopes, and it might even be a good thing. Its nice for libA and libB to both be able to define their own BUILD_TESTS variables without having to be concerned about eachother.
I think of this the same way as the ability to use and reuse the name i as the iterator variable for every for loop that I write in C.

Thank you for the answer! I never considered wrapping each lib in a wrapper...that's genius! I also did not realize block() existed either, so thank you for that insight. I am not at liberty to edit the third party dependencies themselves, just the containing folder so I plan to go with the wrapper option in this case. I do like "block" as a backup, however. Thanks again.
